# bug with listview scrolling during mouse lasso selection (windows 10 update 16299)

Tags: listview, winapi, scroll, mouse

since the latest windows 10 update, all programs that use listview controls (including mine and most [other people's](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/ccdc2b72/?limit=25)) cannot use marquee selection (select by drawing a rectangle round items with the mouse).

the problem is very easy to reproduce, just use any listview with enough items in it that force a horizontal or vertical scrollbar to appear, then try to do this lasso selection with the mouse and you will see the mouse *pointer* jumping to one corner of the screen! (usually bottom right)

this begins with windows 10 build 16299, not before. It only affects 64 bit programs (my 32 bit version works fine). The only 64 bit program that works is windows explorer.

I imagine Microsoft need to get notified of this and provide a solution, because the bug is something that affects all windows desktop programs. But I wonder if anybody has found a workaround for the interim?

Comment: I've noticed this in CuteFTP, which is a 32-bit app, fwiw.

Comment: Does this do anything? `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hList, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER)`

Comment: "_The only 64 bit program that works is windows explorer._" - Explorer no longer uses a list view control as you can see using Spy++.

Comment: @zett42 It does use the list view control, it's just contained inside DirectUIHWND.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think this is a custom control now. It used to have a `SysListView32` child control, but this is no longer the case.

Comment: I can reproduce with a simple dialog-based MFC app. Just drop a listview control on a dialog, insert enough items that a scrollbar appears, try to do rectangle selection. It happens in all view modes. Also `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` doesn't help.

Comment: This bug has already [been reported](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/important-syslistview32-bug-with-multiple-items/9e6198f7-a38a-4614-bc89-4781a9bde748?tm=1509985739913) to MSFT.

Comment: Thanks for reporting - we are working on a fix.

Comment: This happens since Fall Creators. Happens also in Filezilla. Can't believe this is still not fixed, after so many updates... really annoying and ridiculous bug.

Comment: I have noticed this bug two days ago when I did some (big) programming and I was searching a day and a half like crazy, thinking is in my code (VB6)... Since I started to look in my older applications, I was able to reproduce it. And I searched on the internet and got here. Please tell me if there is a fix (a mscomctl.ocx version which works, and how to uninstall the actual version from Windows 10 without uninstalling everything (VB6 and other apps). Sorry, I would put this question in a comment but cannot comment without 50 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting the bug! This has been fixed now. The fix should be available shortly in the next Windows Insider build (17097+).

Comment: finally `*-*`. Most annoying bug ever (since win 95) :P

Comment: the april update 10.0-17134 seems to have fixed the problem, better late than never :)

Comment: The bug is still there in 19041, 32bit apps.

Comment: I am still experiencing this in Windows 10 Professional, build 21H2.  It's only in the 32-bit version of the app.  Very frustrating.  People who use the program might think it's our software, instead of an MS bug.

Answer (score 1):

a stop-gap "solution" is to disable lasso selection (return 1 from LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN). You lose a convenient selection mechanism but at least the mouse won't jump like crazy

hopefully MS will provide a permanent fix to the listview control soon

Answer (score 0):

It's really disturbing how much time a prominent bug like that took to be fixed by Microsoft.

However, it seems to have been fixed after [feature update 1803](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-IT-Pro-Blog/What-s-new-for-IT-pros-in-Windows-10-version-1803/ba-p/188568). (I am not sure whether it had been fixed in some previous update not long ago)

Answer (score 0):

In the MFC 32bit application, the mouse cursor moves to the wrong position when drag and drop "CListCtrl".

PS. 64bit applications are working normally

Environment: Windows 10 Pro 1803

[bug with listview scrolling during mouse lasso selection (windows 10 update 16299)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605376/bug-with-listview-scrolling-during-mouse-lasso-selection-windows-10-update-1629/48675764#48675764)

The above link says that 64-bit application has encountered the same problem as the writing and has already been solved. However, as a result of my work, it works normally on 64bit, but it causes problems in 32bit application.